# PLACEHOLDER - YaSupport

Tags: app, placeholder

The App is for providing support for Yandex Map apps and libs.

Our company provides an API for working with our maps: https://yandex.com/maps-api/docs. We want to help users find answers to questions they ask on the Stack Overflow platform.
We have our own app for the support team and would like to publish their comments and responses on your sites directly from this app via the Stack Overflow API.